# In ggplot2 how to remove all theme + remove some data but keep aspect ratio of the data displayed?

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg

I'am trying to create a base plot and then recreate a modified version of the same plot without some of the data and without any other element (essentially `+ theme_void()`). The difficulty here is to keep the exact size and position of the data that the plot keep between the two versions.

Say I have the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data frame
d <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C"),
                value = c(10, 15, 5))

# Create the original bar plot
g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = d,
           aes(x = group, 
               y = value,
               fill = group)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The aim is to create (and save as .SVG) three plots with one bar per plot (+ theme_void) but with the same position/size as the first one.

**Desired plot 1:**
[image]

**Desired plot 2:**
[image]

**Desired plot 3:**
[image]

I guess one possibility is to make everything else white/transparent, but I want to avoid this approach for I will further manipulate the plot saved as a .SVG, and the elements would be there haunting me (add complexity and bigger file size).

The other approach that I do want to pursue is to get in the middle of the `ggplot2` workflow, stop it in the right time (the drawing context is already given), modify it (as in erase everything but a single bar), and finally render the modified plot.

The package `gginnards` has functions like `delete_layers()` and themes could be replaced with the `%+%` operator, but as far as I could see they modify the size/position (as it should, but this is not what I want).

The closest thing that I found is `ggtrace` package (particularly **"[highjack-ggproto](https://yjunechoe.github.io/ggtrace/#id_3-highjack-ggproto-remove-boxplot-outliers)"**) and the whole discussion (that is still very opaque for me) of `grid/grob`.

I guess I will be learning more on those issues in the weeks to come, but any advice on that would be very appreciated!

**Edit**: from the valuable answers below I must stress:

1. This is a toy example, the real case will incorporate numerous `theme` modifications in the original plot. That´s is to say, a workaround of making the first plot more simple (that would facilitate the comparison) is not a solution in this case.
2. The aim is to save the result in a clean SVG. By clean I mean there is suppose to be only the visible elements in the SVG file (as I inspect its source code). For example, if I have hundreads of points in my plot and I filter for one point, this single point should be alone in the new SVG (in the exact position as it was in the first plot - the plot that has multiple theme modification, title, legends, axis, and so on).

Comment: The difficulty in what you're asking is that ggplot2 automatically resizes objects depending on the presence of items like legends, labels, axes, etc. So to keep them exactly the same size/locations while removing everything but that one object would require some hacking of the tool.

Comment: Precisely! And I guess the hack is between the steps that ggplot2 takes to draw (like the one "highjack-ggproto" uses).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually fairly difficult. The problem is that the exact position of the bars is determined by nested viewports. The easiest solution is probably just to walk the `gTable` of the ggplot object and make all objects that are *not* the bars be `zeroGrobs`

Let's start with the plot itself:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data frame
d <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C"),
                value = c(10, 15, 5))

# Create the original bar plot
g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = d,
           aes(x = group, 
               y = value,
               fill = group)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Our first step is to build this into a `gTable`:

```r
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
```

Note than from now on, if we want to draw the result, we can do:

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Now, let's make everything that isn't the panel a zero grob. The panel is always a `gTree`, so we can do:

```r
gt$grobs <- lapply(gt$grobs, function(x) {
  if(class(x)[1] == 'gTree') x else zeroGrob()
  })
```

Note that this wipes everything except the panel, but leaves all the spacing the same:

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Now we want to do the same thing within the panel, removing everything that isn't a `geom_rect` grob:

```r
panel <- which(lengths(gt$grobs) > 3)

gt$grobs[[panel]]$children <- lapply(gt$grobs[[panel]]$children, function(x) {
  if(grepl('geom_rect', x)) x else zeroGrob()
})
```

This leaves us just with our three bars:

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

To get the individual bars in their own plots, we create three copies of the plot object

```r
gt_list <- list(gt1 = gt, gt2 = gt, gt3 = gt)
```

Now we iterate through this list and remove all but one bar from each:

```r
rectangles <- which(lengths(gt$grobs[[panel]]$children) > 3)

gt_list <- Map(function(x, i) {
  rect <- x$grobs[[panel]]$children[[rectangles]]
  rect$x <- rect$x[i]
  rect$y <- rect$y[i]
  rect$width <- rect$width[i]
  rect$height <- rect$height[i]
  rect$gp <- rect$gp[i]
  x$grobs[[panel]]$children[[rectangles]] <- rect
  x
}, gt_list, seq_along(gt_list))
```

We now have 3 plots with only a single graphical object in each one, yet the position of each graphical element is unchanged compared to the original plot.

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt_list[[1]])
```

[image]

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt_list[[2]])
```

[image]

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt_list[[3]])
```

[image]

Furthermore, we can see that the resulting svg is not full of unnecessary invisible objects; only the bar is written to file:

```r
svg('my.svg')
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt_list[[1]])
dev.off()
```

Resulting in

**my.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="504pt" height="504pt" viewBox="0 0 504 504" version="1.1">
<g id="surface1">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="504" height="504" style="fill:rgb(100%,100%,100%);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;"/>
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(97.254902%,46.27451%,42.745098%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 52.492188 451.675781 L 169.050781 451.675781 L 169.050781 168.375 L 52.492188 168.375 Z M 52.492188 451.675781 "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

And in case there are any nagging doubts that things don't line up, let's save the plots and animate them to prove it:

```r
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))

png('plot1.png')
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt)
dev.off()

Map(function(x, f) {
  png(f)
  grid::grid.newpage()
  grid::grid.draw(x)
  dev.off()
}, gt_list, c('plot2.png', 'plot3.png', 'plot4.png'))

library(magick)

list.files(pattern = 'plot\\d+\\.png', full.names = TRUE) |> 
  image_read() |>
  image_join() |> 
  image_animate(fps=4) |> 
  image_write("barplot.gif")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan! That´s it! I need to start learning the ggplot2 internals, I can sense the power that comes with it!

Comment: @ArthurWelle I don't actually like grob-hacking if I can avoid it, but I don't see a better way here, and the code isn't _too_ difficult.

Comment: One doubt that comes to mind is that you use svg() dev.off() to save it. The result is diferent if I use ggsave(). In this case the svg has a path for the bar, in the ggsave() is a rect element.  The ggsave does not work anymore for now we have a grid, is that it?

Comment: @ArthurWelle correct. You cannot use `ggsave` because it is no longer a ggplot object. It can't be with the constraints that you have set. You either have a `theme_blank` where the margins are set up to precisely copy the dimensions of the original plot (which you don't want to do), _or_ have invisible elements (which cause svg-junk) _or_ you build the plot into graphics objects and select out the ones you want, as in my solution here, but then you no longer have a ggplot object. There is no way in ggplot to have space-filling empty elements upstream of the plot being built.

Comment: Although if you want to use ggsave, you could take the extra step of using `patchwork::wrap_elements` which should allow you to save the grob using `ggsave`

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of [ggtrace](https://yjunechoe.github.io/ggtrace/). Allan is awesome and already did a great job answering your question (and I'm going to shameless copy parts of his reprex/answer here), but I couldn't resist giving a ggtrace solution a stab since you mentioned it!

### The ggtrace workflow

The first step is to intercept the layer's data right as it's about to be passed off to the geom. The drawing of the layer starts in the `ggproto` method `Geom$draw_layer()`, which takes the layer's data in the `data` argument. By "the layer's data", I literally mean `layer_data(g1)`

```r
g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = d,
           aes(x = group, 
               y = value,
               fill = group)) +
  theme_bw()
layer_data(g1)
#>      fill x  y PANEL group flipped_aes ymin ymax xmin xmax colour linewidth linetype alpha
#> 1 #F8766D 1 10     1     1       FALSE    0   10 0.55 1.45     NA       0.5        1    NA
#> 2 #00BA38 2 15     1     2       FALSE    0   15 1.55 2.45     NA       0.5        1    NA
#> 3 #619CFF 3  5     1     3       FALSE    0    5 2.55 3.45     NA       0.5        1    NA
```

Notice how each row of the data represents a bar. If we want the geom layer to draw just one bar, we highjack the argument passed to `Geom$draw_layer()` such that the `data` argument it receives is just *one* of the rows. We can do this with `ggtrace_highjack_args()` by passing the expression `data = data[1,]` (this assignment is the "highjacking" we're doing). Just for good measure, I also `print(data[1,])` so you can check the value as this happens:

```r
gt_bar1 <- ggtrace_highjack_args(
  x = g1, method = Geom$draw_layer,
  values = expression(
    data = print(data[1,])
  )
)
#>      fill x  y PANEL group flipped_aes ymin ymax xmin xmax colour linewidth linetype alpha
#> 1 #F8766D 1 10     1     1       FALSE    0   10 0.55 1.45     NA       0.5        1    NA

gt_bar1
```

[image: gt_bar1]

The output of the highjack function is just another (gtable) grob (with an extra `"ggtrace_highjacked"` class, just for a print method), so you can do your regular grid stuff on it after the fact. Here, I copy Allan's code for "wiping" non-bar elements of the gtable and apply it to `gt_bar1`:

```r
class(gt_bar1)
#> [1] "ggtrace_highjacked" "gtable"             "gTree"              "grob"               "gDesc"

wipe_nonbar <- function(gt) {
  gt$grobs <- lapply(gt$grobs, function(x) {
    if(class(x)[1] == 'gTree') x else zeroGrob()
  })
  panel <- which(lengths(gt$grobs) > 3)
  gt$grobs[[panel]]$children <- lapply(gt$grobs[[panel]]$children, function(x) {
    if(grepl('geom_rect', x)) x else zeroGrob()
  })
  gt
}

gt_bar1_wiped <- wipe_nonbar(gt_bar1)
gt_bar1_wiped
```

[image: gt_bar1_wiped]

Finally, we wrap this workflow into a function and iterate over the number of bars in the layer and save the grobs to a list `gt_bars`:

```r
n_bars <- nrow(layer_data(g1))
gt_bars <- lapply(seq_len(n_bars), function(i) {
  bar_gt <- ggtrace_highjack_args(
    x = g1, method = GeomBar$draw_panel,
    values = rlang::exprs(
      data = data[data$group == !!i,]
    )
  )
  wipe_nonbar(bar_gt)
})
```

Animation:

```r
purrr::iwalk(
  c(list(g1), gt_bars),
  ~ ggsave(filename = paste0(.y, ".png"), plot = .x, path = tempdir())
)
list.files(tempdir(), "\\d.png", full.names = TRUE) |> 
  magick::image_read() |> 
  magick::image_animate(fps = 4)
```

[image: animation]

### Coda

You might be wondering why we need to highjack the ggplot when you could also do `geom_col(data = d[1,])`. The advantage of doing this at "rendering time" is that you can work with a layer data has been augmented for other things like positional information. So we preserve positional adjustments like `position_stack()`:

```r
g2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = d,
           aes(x = 1, 
               y = value,
               fill = group),
           position = position_stack()) +
  theme_bw()
g2
```

[image: g2]

```r
g2_bar2 <- ggtrace_highjack_args(
  g2, Geom$draw_layer,
  values = expression(
    data = data[2,]
  )
)
g2_bar2
```

[image: g2_bar2]

In sum, ggtrace lets you concede less to the "internals" (ggproto, grid, etc.). Bars are constructs we can represent in the grammar, so we should have a higher-level control over them than some other things (like hiding all other elements in the plot - we can let grid have that one). Using this intermediate-level abstraction with ggtrace takes some getting used to, but if this intrigues you please let me know what more of ggtrace-in-action you'd like to see!

### Edit: My take on wiping non-bar elements

I came back to this problem and toyed around with a `wipe_nonbar2()` that's more my "taste":

```r
wipe_nonbar2 <- function(gt) {
  panel <- which(gt$layout$name == "panel")
  gt$grobs[-panel] <- list(zeroGrob())
  rect <- which(grepl("geom_rect", gt$grobs[[panel]]$childrenOrder))
  gt$grobs[[panel]]$children[-rect] <- list(zeroGrob())
  gt
}
```

This preserves the `gList` class of one of the gtable grobs (trivial, but it's a nice property of index-based assignment using `list(zeroGrob())`:

```r
waldo::compare(wipe_nonbar(gt_bar1), wipe_nonbar2(gt_bar1))
#> `old$grobs[[6]]$children` is a list
#> `new$grobs[[6]]$children` is an S3 object of class <gList>, a list
```

Answer (score 1):

If you capture the main steps in a custom function, you can then iterate through each element of the plot, turning the alpha to 0 (i.e. transparent) for the bars you don't want.

```
myplotfun <- function(x) {
  alpha <- rep(0, 3)
  names(alpha) <- c("A", "B", "C")
  alpha[names(alpha) == x] <- 1
  
  p <- ggplot() +
    geom_col(data = d,
             aes(x = group, 
                 y = value,
                 fill = group,
                 alpha = group), show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = alpha) +
    theme_void()
  
  ggsave(paste0(x, ".svg"), p, device = "svg")
}
```

And using `purrr::walk()` to do the iteration.

```
purrr::walk(c("A", "B", "C"), myplotfun)
```

Comment: Thanks Phil! But this approach has two undesired features: 1) the colum in the solo-columns plot is not in the exact same position as the first plot (for the first one has several elements: axis, legends, title, caption, etc). 2) transparency keeps all the elements in the saved SVG. This is hardly a problem in this toy example with three columns, but my use case has hundreds/thousands of elements. I would like to keep every new SVG with only the solo-bar (in this case a rect in the svg).

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted the code and function from @Phil and kept the same plot but hided all legend, titles...

```r
myplotfun <- function(x) {
  alpha <- rep(0, 3)
  names(alpha) <- c("A", "B", "C")
  alpha[names(alpha) == x] <- 1
  
  p <- ggplot() +
    geom_col(data = d,
             aes(x = group, 
                 y = value,
                 fill = group,
                 alpha = group)) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = alpha) +
    theme(
      legend.text = element_text(color = "white"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      legend.key=element_rect(fill = "white")) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0, fill = "white"))) 

  ggsave(paste0(x, ".svg"), p, device = "svg")
  
}

purrr::walk(c("A", "B", "C"), myplotfun)
  
  ggsave(paste0(x, ".svg"), p, device = "svg")
}

purrr::walk(c("A", "B", "C"), myplotfun)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. The problem with @Phil´s approach persists. 1) The saved SVG has all the elements in it (now white); B) the position of the bar is now slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just edited, I had misunderstood your post.

Comment: I could not remove legend without messing up with the scales, I needed to hide it but all the rest is now removed.

Answer (score 1):

The first part can be done if you convert your data to `factor` and specify that dropped levels should be kept:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("A", "B", "C")),
                value = c(10, 15, 5))

# Create the original bar plot
g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = d,
           aes(x = group, 
               y = value,
               fill = group)) +
  theme_void()

g1
```

[image]

```r
g2 <- d %>% 
  filter(group == "A") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(
    x = group, 
    y = value,
    fill = group
  ) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  theme_void()

g2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

However, the legend is tricky and so far I haven't found a way. Maybe a workaround that works for you is to generate all plots without a legend (setting `theme(legend.position = "none")`) and then creating the legend in an extra step and place it somewhere where it fits into the layout? You can extract the legend with `cowplot::get_legend(g1)` or `ggpubr::get_legend(g1)`.

Comment: Thanks Starja! I see you stated the first plot with theme_void. That is a no go for me. This is simple a toy example, the real case is a more complex plot with lots of theme modification. We start with a plot with full of changes and then I want to reduce it to a single bar keeping the same view (exact size and position as the first plot).  That´s why I guess the way to go is with modifications in the grid/grob phase.

Comment: I see. The you indeed might need to toy with the grobs, I've found these functions, maybe they are helpful: `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))`